# Pytorch grid_sample change grid points use

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch

I'm using torch.nn.functional.grid_sample(input, grid) and came up with a question. I use it in an image warping setting, so with input being the image and grid representing the warping grid.

As far as I understood it, grid represents the 'pull' grid, in the sense that, at position x, output[x] is given by the values of input near the position given by grid[x].

So my question is the following: is there a way to change grid_sample, or is there another function in pytorch that I don't know of, to make something like grid_sample where grid is seen as the 'push' grid and not the pull one? So that at position x, input[x] and its neighbors are used for the output at position grid[x].

I hope that my doubt is clear and makes some sense, thanks in advance.

I tried to look online but couldn't find some explanation on this topic.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you would like to have for [`grid_sample`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.grid_sample.html) what [`torch.scatter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter_.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_) is for [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html). Are you aware in that case a pixel in the output might be affected by more than one pixel from the input image? What would be the desired reduction on the scattered values: last, mean, sum... ?